# Add a background to a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I want to add a background to my JFrame, but I can't get it done.
I have searched on the internet to find to some tutorials on it.
I am still a newbie and I want to learn these things.
This is what I have so far.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Desktop;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel BackgroundLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Gui frame = new Gui();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Gui() {
        setTitle("Exile Launcher");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 563);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        BufferedImage BackgroundImage = null;
        try {
            BackgroundImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/Background.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        JLabel BackgroundLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(BackgroundImage));

        add(BackgroundLabel);

        JButton HomeButton = new JButton("Home");
        HomeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://www.google.nl").toURI());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        HomeButton.setBounds(10, 9, 50, 50);
        contentPane.add(HomeButton);

        JButton ForumButton = new JButton("Vote");
        ForumButton.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
        contentPane.add(ForumButton);

        JButton VoteButton = new JButton("New button");
        VoteButton.setBounds(10, 131, 50, 50);
        contentPane.add(VoteButton);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at gui.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:59)
    at gui.Gui$1.run(Gui.java:36)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've got it running.  First off your using null layout but not specifying the aspects you need to be focusing on.  You don't actually create your background image when you just do "add(backgroundLabel);" you need to run backgroundLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(int x, int y, width, hight);   I'm going to give you the entire code.  Make sure you have the file path reset to what you need.

Just drop it in, set your path and it should run.  You will need to make sure the class name matches whatever your expecting to have but here you go:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final JPanel contentPane;
private JLabel BackgroundLabel;
Image background;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Gui frame = new Gui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Gui() {
    this.setTitle("Exile Launcher");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 563);
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    this.contentPane.setBorder(null);
    this.setContentPane(this.contentPane);
    this.contentPane.setLayout(null);

    try {
        this.background = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/Background.jpg"));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final JLabel backgroundLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.background));
    backgroundLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 563));
    this.add(backgroundLabel);

    final JButton HomeButton = new JButton("Home");
    HomeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://www.google.nl").toURI());
            } catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final URISyntaxException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    HomeButton.setBounds(10, 9, 50, 50);
    this.contentPane.add(HomeButton);

    final JButton ForumButton = new JButton("Vote");
    ForumButton.setBounds(10, 70, 50, 50);
    this.contentPane.add(ForumButton);

    final JButton VoteButton = new JButton("New button");
    VoteButton.setBounds(10, 131, 50, 50);
    this.contentPane.add(VoteButton);
}


// Final Piece to add an image to the jpanel
public void paintComponent(final Graphics pic) {
    this.paintComponent(pic);
    pic.drawImage(this.background, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there something you didn't approve of? [xx4m4zingxx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2675845/xx4m4zingxx)

Comment: I can't type that:

public PrimaryJPanel(){
setBackground()
}

It will give errors something that I have to add void and when I do that I still get errors.

Comment: public "CLASS"() {
setBackground(); //calls a METHOD

Comment: What should I do then? public "CLASSNAME"() { setBackground(); ?

Comment: and you can't just use set bounds for your other elements.  You won't get the result your looking for.  You need someButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y, width, hight));

Comment: Omg, this worked, but I got one more thing. the buttons only appear after I hovered over them. How can I fix this?

Comment: make sure they're: whateverYourButtonNameIs.setVisible(true);

The other thing you can do is make sure they're added after the JLabel you have as your background (So that they're added on top).

Also please accept and upvote the solution if it worked

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the answer and I added the JLabel as last so now I can see the buttons directly from start.

Answer (score -1):

Exception is Self Explanatory

```
 BackgroundImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/Background.jpg"));
```

You are passing illegalArgument to `read()` method of `ImageIO class`

As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) syas

```
public static BufferedImage read(File input)
                          throws IOException
```

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with
>   an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently
>   registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no
>   registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream,
>   null is returned.

You need to pass the File Class Object like this :

```
 BackgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Ruud\\workspace\\ExileLauncher\\Images\\Background.jpg"));
```

**Note : You need to pass the absolute path of the file where it is located**

A suggestion: if you are catching an `Exception` try to print it so that you may know the root cause.

```
 try {
 BackgroundImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/Background.jpg"));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();// Here printing the stackTrace of Exception
        }
```

Comment: I changed it to:BackgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/Background.jpg"));
and now it says:javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
My Background.jpg is in the src/Images Directory.http://prntscr.com/68iw2n

Comment: Where is your file actually located ? please provide the absolute path

Comment: I don't get an error now, but there is no background yet.

Comment: This is the absolute path: C:\Users\Ruud\workspace\ExileLauncher\Images, but I want to create a jar file from it later.